# Rails ActionCable / Turbolinks chat issue: posting duplicate messages

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, chat, turbolinks, actioncable

I'm having an issue with an ActionCable and Turbolinks.  I've set up a chat app similar to the [example chat app shared by DHH](https://hectorperezarenas.com/2015/12/26/rails-5-tutorial-how-to-create-a-chat-with-action-cable/).

In order to have multiple chat rooms and pass a chat room ID to the ActionCable subscription initializer, I have something like this:

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load",function(){
  var pod_slug = $("#pod_slug_value").val();
  App.pods = App.cable.subscriptions.create(
    { channel: 'PodsChannel', pod_slug: pod_slug },
    {
    received: function(data) {
      if ( $(".chat-stream").length ){
        $(data.message).appendTo($(".chat-stream"));
        $(".chat-stream").scrollTop($(".chat-stream")[0].scrollHeight);
      }
    },

    speak: function(message, pod_slug) {
      return this.perform('speak',{
        message: message,
        pod_slug: pod_slug
      });
    }
  });

  // captures text input from input field
  captureMessage();

});
```

However, when I click around the app and come back to the page, Turbolinks seems to be binding the subscription handler multiple times and now when I submit a message, I get duplicate messages in the chat stream.

I've tried slicing this problems in every which way.  I don't have the problem when I don't preface the subscription handler with:

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load",function(){...
```

But then I am unable to get the chat room id (pod_slug), because the document DOM doesn't load before the javascript executes.

It seems like this problem would have a simple solution as both ActionCable and Turbolinks are heavily supported by Basecamp.  Many of the [demo chat tutorials](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-a-chat-app-with-rails-5-actioncable-and-devise/) suggest setting up chat in exactly this way.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same issue and fixed it in this way

```
if (!App.pods) {
  App.pods = App.cable.subscriptions.create(
   { channel: 'PodsChannel', pod_slug: pod_slug },
   { ... /* and so on */ }
}
```

Every time you reload page, 'turbolinks:load' event works, so you have to check whether App.pods object has been already created.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: But doesn't app.pods contain references to all the different chat rooms?  So checking to see if it exists would prevent you from starting new rooms once one room have been created.  No?

Comment: @Lorenz Yes, you are right. In my case, I need only one channel, so this solution worked for me. But now I'm interested in this question, so I'll try to find out how can I help you.

Comment: I did something similar to this to temporarily solve my problem:
 'if (!App.pods || JSON.parse(App.pods.identifier).pod_slug != pod_slug){'
 but it feels very hackish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `App.cable.subscriptions.remove` to remove a subscription returned by `App.cable.subscriptions.create`. So maybe check if `App.pods` is set, and if so remove it before you subscribe again.

Answer (score 0):

I like your approach, [MaruniakS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6198976/maruniaks).  Digging into the consumer object, it looks like it has a test to see if it's disconnected.  Changing just the first line, we could also do:

```
if (!App.pods || App.pods.consumer.connection.disconnected) {
  App.pods = App.cable.subscriptions.create(
    { channel: 'PodsChannel', pod_slug: pod_slug },
    { ... /* and so on */ }
}
```